# Finding the smallest possible value with the information

Tags: probability, fractions

A bag contains counters of 3 different colours. Given that 3/10 of them are red counters, 1/8 of them are green counters and 23/40 are yellow counters.

Find the smallest possible number of counters in the bag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Find the lowest common multiple of all the denominators in your fractions, this is your answer.

Comment: I got the answer but is there an explanation for it? I didn't quite understand why why took the LCM on denominators

Comment: To add fractions together, they all need to have the same denominator.  All these fractions need to be summed together to equal 1/1.  Typically you could do this by multiplying the denominators together - 10*8*40, giving a bag size of 320. However you can also do it with a bag size of 40, which is LCM(10,8,40).

Comment: I should also say, the denominator is the bag size.  If we had three bags here, the first bag would have 10 counters, the second 8 counter, and the third 40 counters.  However to make them all one bag, you make the denominator match all three fractions.  LCM is typically the best way of doing this.